# How does python interpret numbers with leading zeroes

Tags: python

I'm new with python, I'm using python 2.7
when I typed this on python shell:

```
print 01
print 010
print 0100
print 01000
```

It gives this result

```
1
8
64
512
```

I tried to understand why it gave that but unfortunately I didn't get the point.

Comment: to print out those specific numbers (if starting with 0), just use them as strings:
`print '01'`
`print '010'` etc

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If a number starts with `0`, it is interpreted as octal, or base 8. Just do:

```
print 1
print 10
print 100
print 1000
```

And your problem will be solved.

More on octal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Here is a way to understand octal easier:

> octal 1 is decimal (normal numbers) 1
>
> octal 2 : decimal 2
>
> ...
>
> octal 7 : decimal 7
>
> octal 10: decimal 8
>
> octal 11: decimal 9
>
> octal 12: decimal 10
>
> ...
>
> octal 17: decimal 15
>
> octal 20: decimal 16

and so on. Octal just uses digits from 0 to 7.

Hope this helped!

Comment: By the way, this is only correct for Python 2. In Python 3, the `0o` prefix is mandatory; a leading `0` on its own is a `SyntaxError`. Also, you should say that octal numbers only use *digits* from 0 to 7.

Answer (score 10):

Python interprets a number starting with `0` as `octal` which is `base 8`.You can work out the base using the binary string `10` as `b^1 === b`  where `b` is the base.

```
# print the decimal value of the binary number 10
>>> print 0b10
2
# print the decimal value of the octal number 10    
>>> print 010
8
# print the decimal value of the hexadecimal number 10
>>> print 0x10
16
```

In any base the symbol `1` is always the `decimal` value `1` because `b^0 === 1` for all `b` as reading right to left the index of a number starts at `0`.

```
# print the decimal value of the binary number 1
>>> print 0b001
1
# print the decimal value of the octal number 1
>>> print 0001
1
# print the decimal value of the hexadecimal number 1
>>> print 0x001
1
```

Once the base is interpreted (`0`,`0b`,`0x`) leading `0` aren't important.

The number of symbols needed for a base is `b` where the largest symbols is equal to `b-1`

```
            Base (b)   Number of Symbols (b)    Symbols (0 : b-1)
Binary      2          2                        0,1
Octal       8          8                        0,1,2,3,4,5,7,6,7
Decimal     10         10                       0,1,2,3,4,5,7,6,7,8,9
```

The largest value that can be represented by a number is `(b^n)-1` where `n` is the number of digits. Given a 3 digit number the largest decimal value is `(10^3)-1 = 999`, in octal `(8^3)-1 = 511 (decimal)` which is `777` in base 8 and in binary `(2^3)-1 = 7 (decimal)` which is `111` in base 2. So you can see that with less symbols *(a lower base)* the value you can represent decreases given a fixed number of digits.