# Python datetime timedelta issues with leading 0 in days parm

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Ok So it looks like there may be a bug or something is missing in the documentation. If you add a leading 0 to the days parm for example, you will get a different result than without it, See sample:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(063)
datetime.date(2014, 1, 4)
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(63)
datetime.date(2013, 12, 23)
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=63)
datetime.date(2013, 12, 23)
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=063)
datetime.date(2014, 1, 4)
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=063)
datetime.date(2014, 1, 4)
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=int(063))
datetime.date(2014, 1, 4)
```

Comment: You are giving it octal numbers.

Comment: This is not a datetime problem but a misunderstanding of Python's integer literals.

Comment: Thanks yeah figured it out, hopefully this helps others.

Comment: Your old title was just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to timedelta, I tried looking at this manual first:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Then I tried something obvious:

```
>>> int = 063
>>> int
51
```

It looks like a leading in a numeric type is understood as a octal value to python. Also, if it starts with 0x its considered a hex which makes sense. The leading 0 really threw me off but it is also answered in this thread:

[How does python interpret numbers with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431324/how-does-python-interpret-numbers-with-leading-zeroes)

Answer (score 1):

A leading `0` means the number is interpreted as an octal number (base 8). So 063 is actually 51 in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

`063` is an octal number:

```
>>> 063
51
```

because (6 * 8) + 3 is 51.

From the [integer literals documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals):

> ```
> octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+ | "0" octdigit+
> ```

In Python 3, the `"0" octdigt+` part of the grammar was dropped, because too many people kept tripping over this; `063` would be a syntax error in Python 3.