# Bitshifting with and without leading zero

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I wonder why adding one or multiple leading zeros to an integer in Python leads to different results when using the bitshift-operators:

```
In:  10<<1
Out: 20
```

Adding a "0" in front of the integer:

```
In:  010<<1
Out: 16
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with bitshifting, only with python 2 treating integer literals starting with `0` as octal.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, I found the answer is quite simple - but maybe it's worth sharing it:

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13431333/872535), adding a leading zero to an integer will cause Python to interpret it as an octal/base 8.

```
In:  int("010",8)
Out: 8
```

Thus, left-shifting the octal (or decimal 8), i.e. multipicaton by 2**1, leads to 16

```
In:  8<<1
Out: 16
```

Comment: If you already found an answer, why did you post a self-answered question? That's just creating a duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it creates a duplicate. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/   (In fact, there is an option to answer your own question).

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question, but that doesn't mean you need to create one for each and every situation where you can use an octal number literal.

Comment: It is not the act of self-answering that I am protesting here! Note that the two questions on my profile are self-answers too.