# How to make 0 get counted as an integer?

Tags: python

Each time I put 0 at the beginning of my 7 digit code it is ignored and not times by 3. I have a feeling that I need to change something from `str()` to `int()` (and vice-versa) but I may be wrong. I would be grateful for assistance in this matter.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve and what you are doing in your own words, don't just paste your code.

Comment: Either you are entering *digits* (characters), or you are entering a *number*. Numbers don't start with 0; that's not part of their numeric value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does python interpret numbers with leading zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431324/how-does-python-interpret-numbers-with-leading-zeroes)

Comment: Are you using Python 2 perhaps? In that case `input()` returns the *Python interpretation* of the input, and not a string. Use `raw_input` in that case.

Comment: @cricket_007: where is the OP using a Python integer literal?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Guess you're right. That's why it's a *possible* duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Numeric literals starting with `0` are interpreted as being in base 8.

```
>>> int("755", base=8)
493
>>> 0755
493
>>> input("> ")
> 0755
493
```

Comment: There is no such literal in the code. Perhaps we need to get some clarification from the OP instead?

Comment: if they're using `input()`, and entering `0XYZ`, it might be the same thing. But yes, clarification could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using raw_input() instead of input(). Input() evaluates the user input as python code, where raw_input() evaluates the entry as entered.