# How to print all elements of a list with trailing zeroes in python

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and started learning my first programming language in python.

**My code:**

```
a=[0001,0052,1122,0127]

for i in a:
        nums = '{:05}'.format(i)
        print(nums)
```

Output :

```
00001
00042
01122
00087
```

**Expected Output:**

```
00001
00052
01122
00127
```

I am not getting what is wrong here.

Someone had closed the question but I am getting how can I do this?
I tried this also,but not working. please help

```
for i in a:
        nums = '{:05}'.format(int(i, 8))
        print(nums)
```

Comment: Numbers that start with `0` are interpreted as octal, not decimal.

Comment: `52` octal is `42` decimal.

Comment: Just remove the trailing zeros in your list. You should have `[1, 52, 1122, 127]`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13431333/4257747) on the duplicated question.