# Redirect to value to variable and character cut logic

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7

if a = 110 I want to make  b = 11

if a = 120 I want to make  b = 12

if a = 010 I want to make  b = 1

if a = 020 I want to make  b = 2

Is this achievable with any logic in a Python script?

Comment: Yes, of course that's achievable. But this isn't a tutorial or code-writing service; [learn some Python](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F), and actually *try to achieve it*. It seems like you just want `b` to be equal to `a` divided by ten, in which case how do you *think* you do it?!

Comment: what to do in case of 102?

Comment: Also be aware that `020 == 16` in Python 2.x, as the leading zero means octal integer literals. Or do you mean they're strings, like `'020'` (in which case including the quotes would be helpful)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe a = 010 and b = 10 and c = a/b i am getting 0

Comment: @Ashish my case i wont get 102 value..in my case only 110, 010,020,030,130,150 and so on

Comment: As I said, it's an octal literal. `010 == 8` (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13431324/3001761) and, due to integer division in Python 2.x (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1267869/3001761), `8 / 10 == 0`. Please give more context as to the actual problem you're trying to solve, give an actual [mcve].

Comment: yes done that. check my code.

Comment: @Ashish your answer won't work with e.g. `a = 010`.

Comment: input provided will be in string or int?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, is there way we can convert 020 to 20. So then i will use divide rule.

Comment: @sagar well where is the 020 coming from? How are you converting it to Python datatypes? Again, give a [mcve] and provide some context.

Comment: this 020 is provide by user say a = raw_input('Enter trunk number'), these number user will provide always in terms of 010,020..100,110,120...

Comment: Well `int` uses base 10 by default, so you **don't** have `020`. This is why a [mcve] is useful; it's less ambiguous than a description. [Edit] the question, and explain why simply dividing by ten is a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonrspare and i used int and it works fine

Comment: If you no longer have a problem I'd recommend deleting the question.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to replace all the zeros:

```
a = 110
b = int(str(a).replace('0',''))
print b
```

**output**

```
11
```

Comment: When it's unclear what the OP is actually asking for, as it is here, it's best not to answer until they've edited to clarify.